# Why the resize event only fires once

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function run every time the "resize" event fires out. 
  But there is something that prevents it from happening. When I write an anonymous function and console log something when the event 'resize' fires - it works. Help me understand why this may could have happened.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", getNumberOfShelves(arr, width));

function getNumberOfShelves( arra, w ) {
 if(wrap.firstChild) {
    wrap.removeChild(wrap.firstChild);
 }
 if(w >= 1126) {
     var numberOfBooks = 4;
     var arrayOfArrays = [];

     for (var i=0; i<arra.length; i+=numberOfBooks) {
          arrayOfArrays.push(arra.slice(i, i+numberOfBooks));
     }

     array1 = arrayOfArrays[0];
     array2 = arrayOfArrays[1];
     create(array1);
     create(array2);
}
```

Comment: or bind the function or wrap the function in another anonymous function, because right now, you are just calling the function and not binding it to resize listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like you're not passing the arguments of the function properly, try this:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
    getNumberOfShelves(arr, width)
});
```

instead of the first line

Comment: It worked! Could you write a consice comment about how it works?

Comment: window.addEventListener expects the function as the second argument, for example if you want to call function named 'calculate()' after 'resize' you would do: window.addEventListener("resize",calculate); notice that we don't put the parenthesis there, if you want to pass in arguments you can put them after the comma like so: window.addEventListener("resize",calculate,2,3); this is equivalent of calling calculate(2,3); in my solution you create an anonymous function (a one with no name) that will be called straight away, which will call your function with the given arguments.

Answer (score 4):

You're not passing a reference to a function for handling the `resize` event. You're *calling* a function while declaring that `addEventListener`.

So it's only going to run once, and then whenever resize happens, nothing else happens because there is no function to call back (since the return of your `getNumberOfShelves` is the `undefined` primitive).

Instead, start with `window.addEventListener("rezise", event => handleResize(event));` and then create a function like

```js
handleResize(event) {
  ...
}
```

which does whatever you actually need done.

Answer (score 3):

The addEventListener function takes two arguments, the first one being the event type, in your case the `resize` and the second one a callback function. When you write:

`getNumberOfShelves(arr, width)` javascript will run that function immediately and only once.

If you want to run it everytime that event fires you need to pass a function reference.

If the function doesn't have any parameters you could only do 
`window.addEventListener("resize", getNumberOfShelves);`

But in your case it has two parameters so you want to do 
`window.addEventListener("resize", () => getNumberOfShelves(arr, width));`.

Hope this simple explanation helped you, for more information about the function read this:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

when you add () to the end of a function, you call/invoke/execute that function.
In an event listener, you want the function to be called by the event listener, not you, so you don't call it there unless of course your function returns a function.